flutter_local_notifications: NullPointerException when restarting the foreground service with a null intent on Android 14 & 12
I'm getting a Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ForegroundService@d50aeda with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference
It seems to happen when the app is in the background and the user taps on the foregroundservice notification. I'm not able to reproduce it myself, caught by Crashlytics.
Using the default: 'START_STICKY', I would just need the tap on the foreground to open the app.
Current implementation:
Future<void> _startForegroundService(
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin,
  int id,
  String title,
  String body,
  AndroidNotificationDetails details,
) async {
  try {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.startForegroundService(
          id,
          title,
          body,
          notificationDetails: details,
          // startType:
        );
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error starting foreground service: $e');
  }
}

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static void notificationTapBackground(
      NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    // Handle background notification tap here

    print(
        'Notification tapped in background: ${notificationResponse.actionId}');
  }

I'm unable to reproduce this in debug.
